# Objective C Post Multipart/data Text Error

Tags: objective-c, upload, httprequest

I have a problem with an `http Post request` the situation is follows:

I have to send a post request with text and Img here the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *eventRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_urlRequest cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:500];
 NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

//Set header Http POST
[eventRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[eventRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parameter1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[self postParametre] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//Image upload
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: immage/jpg \r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"immagine.jpg\""dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:data];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Close boundary
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// set request body
[eventRequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Stampa Dati inviati: %@", string);

// Http header Content-Lenght
[eventRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

self.theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:eventRequest delegate:self];

if (self.theConnection) {
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"Connection Problem");
}
```

can see that i set the i set the multipart/form-data for `"Content-Type"` in the first part of body i set che text and in the second i set the image, but the image was upload correctly but without the "extension" and in the first i set the text to send but the text apparently was not set or the format was not read to server.

the method `[self postParametre]` return a `NSMutableString` with this format "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3".

anyone can help me?

regards.

Comment: At the first glance, there seems no error. But hand-crafting a multipart form request is error prone. You might check with NSURLConnection's  `canHandleRequest` whether the request is valid. Though the method cannot confirm this for 100%. Also, please check and NSLog all errors you can get. Also, take the constructed data, convert it to a string and print it to the console (with a zero size image) and hand check the boundaries and those stuff.

Comment: I also expect you have implemented all the delegate methods properly, did you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.

AFHTTPClient has one method multipartFormRequestWithMethod. This will uploaded images in multi part.

Comment: I would prefer to use NSMutableURLRequest